# comparing pictures in JS in testcomplete

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

So what I'm essentially trying to do is to verify that a picture that shows up on a web page is what I'm expecting it to be. I understand that I can compare two pictures using the following code:

```
var MyPic = page.someLocation.Picture();

Regions.Compare(MyPic, PictureToCompare)
```

What I'm having trouble figuring out is how to create the PictureToCompare var. I want this to be held onto inside of testcomplete as the image to check what is currently on my web page against. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an empty Picture object using the [Utils.Picture](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/69838/) property and initialize it with an image using the [LoadFromFile](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/71206/) method:

```
var PictureToCompare = Utils.Picture;
PictureToCompare.LoadFromFile("c:\\myImage.png");
```